# Features and Configuration of the Typescript Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, debugging, configuration, typescript

I'm interested in developing with typescript on linux. So I found the above mentioned plugin. I installed eclipse and also the eclipse-typescript plugin as described [here](https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript). Now I can edit typescript files and see the highlighting. But it is not possible to debug a script. When I try to debug it, there is no debug configuration available.

Is the plugin able to debug a typescript?

I also read in [this wiki](https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript/wiki), but this single page doesn't help me. I googled around and did not found any howto or help...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is the plugin able to debug a typescript?

It isn't supported. Based on my empirical (but certain) observation of : https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript/tree/master/Bridge/src

You could debug the generated JavaScript though (and I highly recommend you do that anyways). And in fact learn to use google chrome debug tools (you'll thank me someday) since they have a live edit and continue, repl, profiler etc.

Alternatively you can try WebStorm which fully supports debugging TypeScript on linux.

Answer (score 0):

At the same time, TypEcs (another TypeScript plugin for Eclipse) features debugging - http://typecsdev.com/. The plugin supports two modes of TypeScript debug:

1. Standalone: this mode is suitable for debugging server-side NodeJS applications written on TypeScript,
2. Web Remote: this mode is connected to Google Chrome web browser and allows you to debug TypeScript web application.

So you can try this one.